# webpack-resolve-alias to resolve dependecy's sub-dependency

Tags: vue.js, webpack, node-modules, vue-cli, pdf.js

I'm sort of stuck with one problem and googling it for about three hours brought me nowhere.

Here's the problem. I'm trying to develop my own custom PDF viewer based on PDF.JS lib. Officially it is distributed on npm as `pdfjs-dist` package. However I need to extend a few classes that are not accessible in `pdfjs-dist`. So I `npm install`'ed or `yarn add`'ed the original repo https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js.git. This way I have access to classes I need. Inside pdf.js there are core lib that is stored in `pdf.js/src/` and a pdf-viewer app that is stored in `pdf.js/web/`.

Inside that `pdf.js/web/` app core lib (pdf.js) is referenced via `pdfjs-lib` alias that is resolved to `pdf.js/src/` during pdf.js inner build process by gulp.

For example `pdf.js/web/base_viewer.js`:

```js
import { AnnotationLayerBuilder } from './annotation_layer_builder';
import { createPromiseCapability } from 'pdfjs-lib';
import { PDFPageView } from './pdf_page_view';
```

So now I'm trying to import that `pdf.js/web/base_viewer.js` in my app that is using latest Webpack 4 (I guess), and this `pdfjs-lib` sub-dependency is not resolved.

I've tried webpack's resolve-alias mechanism (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/):

```
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'pdfjs-lib': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/pdf.js/src/')
      },
    }
```

...but looks like it resolves dependencies only of my own App, but not sub-dependencies of my dependency.

Just in case I'm building Vue 3.0 app using vue-cli and access webpack config this way: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html, but don't think it matters.

Any help from Webpack gurus here?

Thanks.